# Extract URL from Internet popup window?

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code that I am using to extract data from a sports website. My issue is that I am unable to locate the url for a pop-up window on this website - therefore, I am not sure how I could extract data from this window. The pop-window can be accessed by clicking the blue icon next to a players name, and the data I need is on the second tab of the pop-up window.

```
Sub Extract_goals()

Dim url As String, links_count As Integer
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, row As Integer
Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object
Dim tr_coll As Object, tr As Object
Dim td_coll As Object, td As Object

links_count = 40
For i = 1 To links_count

    url = "http://fantasy.premierleague.com/stats/elements/?stat_filter=goals_scored&element_filter=0&page=" & i & ""

    Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
    XMLHTTP.send

    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText

    Set tbl = html.getelementsbytagname("Table")

    Set tr_coll = tbl(0).getelementsbytagname("TR")

    For Each tr In tr_coll
        j = 1
        Set td_col = tr.getelementsbytagname("TD")

        For Each td In td_col
            Cells(row + 1, j).Value = td.innerText
            j = j + 1
        Next
        row = row + 1
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Any help with this is appreciated.

Thanks,
Shahid

Comment: Will they hyperlink completely change each time? If you do your steps manually, and get the URL, can you see some kind of pattern that you can work in to your macro?  Or are you saying that even manually, you're not sure how to get the URL?

Comment: The blue button that you click, if you right click and view URL, is it a relatively "stable" url? Or is it javascript or something?  What Icon are you clicking on the fantasy page? the info about the players?

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes, even doing it manually, I am unable to get the url. The address bar url doesn't change and if I go through the data extraction module in excel manually, the url does change but when I copy that url and paste it in a browser, the pop-window doesn't open (and needless to say that url doesn't extract the data either).

Comment: @BruceWayne - Yes, the info about the players (the blue "i" button) and the second tab "history" has the data I am trying to extract. I have tried the copy link method and the url doesn't seem stable, nor does it extract the history table.

Comment: Hm, I'm not too good with using the web and VBA, but I suspect you'll want to somehow access the link next to the `i` symbol, which is a class `ismInfo ismViewProfile`. I'll keep looking around for ideas.  Viewing the source, each player has an id, Vardy is `#170`...so the URL will likely use that. If someone is better at reading HTML/Java, I'm sure you can find it.

Comment: @BruceWayne -Thanks! I'll keep looking and look into that class you mentioned. If you come accross anything that can help, please let me know.

Comment: I've got you into the pop-up window. Once I figure out to click on the history tab, I will post up an answer. Or do you just need the URL for the pop-up and then can move on from there?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - I'd appreciate if you can figure out the click on the history tab and then post the answer. Realistically, I'll take whatever I can get but I honestly don't have the skills to write this from scratch and will probably end up on forums again.

Comment: Hi @ScottHoltzman - just checking in if you had any luck with this. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: @ShahidBeig - I ran out of time to play with it. I got somewhere, but not all the way, so I didn't want to post anything. If I get time to dig in again and find something, I will post it.... Actually, I will post a *partial answer*, as I did discover how to cull out the URL for the pop-up window. I just did not discover how to cull data out of that window, but perhaps you can figure it out.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - Thank you. Really appreciate this. I'll try to work with this further.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - I have tried working with this for quite sometime now and I even put to the side and tried coming back to it but no luck, if you can help me figure out this code, I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I used a different method to get this (by creating an `Internet Explorer` object), because I could not get it to work exactly the same way using the `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` object.

I got as far as finding the URL of the popup window, but have yet to discover how to pull data from that window. If I have more time, I will play more, but perhaps this gets you over the hump and you can figure out the rest.

```
Sub Extract_goals2()

Dim ie As Object
Dim doc As Object

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With ie

    .Visible = True

    links_count = 40
    For i = 1 To links_count

        .navigate "http://fantasy.premierleague.com/stats/elements/?stat_filter=goals_scored&element_filter=0&page=" & i & ""

        Do
            DoEvents
        Loop Until Not .busy Or .readyState <> 4

        Set doc = .document

        Dim tbl As Object
        Set tbl = doc.getelementsbytagname("Table")

        Dim tr_coll As Object
        Set tr_coll = tbl(0).getelementsbytagname("TR")

        For Each tr In tr_coll
            j = 1
            Set td_col = tr.getelementsbytagname("TD")

                For Each td In td_col

                    If j = 2 Then 'only do this on 2nd table column

                        Set td_a = td.getelementsbytagname("a")
                        Debug.Print td_a(o).href 'this will provide the exact URL
                        td_a(o).Click 'this will actually open the pop-up box

                        'my thoughts were then to work with the elements in this URL to extract what you need

                    Else

                        Cells(row + 1, j).Value = td.innerText

                    End If

                    j = j + 1

                Next

                row = row + 1

        Next

    Next

End With

End Sub
```